# No route matches [POST] "/contacts/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong here. Hoping it is something simple. I'm just trying to figure out a simple contact form.

Thanks in advance.

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
       redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Message sent."
    else
       redirect_to new_contact_path, notice: "Error occured."
    end
  end

  private
    def contact_params
       params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end
end
```

new.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3 class="text-center">Contact Us</h3>

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>
  <div class="well">
    <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :comments %>
        <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>

        <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to: 'pages#home'
    get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
    resources :contacts
end
```

Here is my rails routes command

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
        root GET    /                            pages#home
       about GET    /about(.:format)             pages#about
    contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)          contacts#index
             POST   /contacts(.:format)          contacts#create
 new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)      contacts#new
edit_contact GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format) contacts#edit
     contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#show
             PATCH  /contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#update
             PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#update
             DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)      contacts#destroy
```

Like I said, I have tried everything I can think of and can't find my mistake. I need your help!

Comment: When this error occurs?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in any of these files? Do you have any other links? No route matches [POST] “/contacts/new” it's trying to send a post request to "new". Do you have any other `link_to`?

Comment: This error occurs when clicking the submit button.

Comment: Your form is trying to reach an inexistent route (post /contacts/new). Try replacing `<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>` with `<%= form_for @contact, url: contacts_path, method: 'POST' do |f| %>`.

Comment: mrlew I tried your suggestion. Still getting the error message

Comment: Same error or different one?

Comment: by default `resources/new` should be `get` requested which is reflected on output of `rake routes`. have you anywhere hardcoded a post request to new action?

Comment: Looks nothing wrong with above code.

Comment: I'm getting the same error mrlew

Comment: marmeladze no i haven't

Comment: In your create method, try doing `redirect_to contact_path(@contact.id)` to see if the error disappears.

Comment: Look at your **rake routes**  and you'll notice the reason. `new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)      contacts#new` is a `GET`, not a `POST`, so you really don't have a route for `POST /contacts/new`.

Comment: Shannon, I got the same error

Comment: can you please share the appropriate lines where you access the `contacts/new` by clicking it? this might be in index page, or on any other page.

Comment: @marmeladze    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", new_contact_path %></li>
          </ul>

Comment: No idea what I did but somehow it works now

Comment: so, when you click that link, it says no route matches to `contacts/new`? tres interessant..

Comment: @marmeladze no it was when I pressed the submit button in the new.html.erb code I included above

Comment: debug your app, maybe you are missing anything. stop and run your dev server again. everything seems completely ok